# Edittext styling not opening keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles

I am creating style for all edittext in teme.

```
 <style name="edittextStyle">
            <item name="android:drawablePadding">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_round</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
            <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/gray</item>
            <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
            <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
            <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        </style>

   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/edittextStyle</item>

        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_medium</item>
    </style>
```

It's working as expected and all edittexts are styled with white background. **But they are not getting Input.**

If I put style attribs directly to edittext , it's getting input. What am I missing ?

Comment: down voters please add comments .

Comment: try inheriting from a base-edittext style, maybe you are not setting the editable attribute or something of that sort

Comment: ok let me try. and will let you know . @Alex.F

Comment: Can you tell me the  SDK  version which is used to create your emulator ?

Comment: I am testing in device - Asus zenfone 5.

Comment: yes you were correct @Alex.F. adding  `parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText"` did the trick. Thank you. One silly question and I got downvote. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got answer from @Alex.F , this did the trick.

change

```
<style name="edittextStyle">
```

to

```
<style name="edittextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
```

Comment: Helped me here! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon a similar issue. When customizing a `widget` like `edittext` the best way to avoid problems is to inherit a parent style like `Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText`, for example.